# Android - Getting messages from socket server

Tags: android

I'm trying to show server messages (i use Python for the server side) on the client. But i have a problem with this code.
when i add this code my app crash but when i remove the code it will work

**problem with this code**

MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

```
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            text.setText(message);
                        }
                    });
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private Socket socket;
    private TextView text;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 12;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.1";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        String message = "";
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);


                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
                        new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead;
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    message = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            text.setText(message);
                        }
                    });

                }

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: whats you error? try to implement the socket listeners to get the socket onOpen or onError for example...

Comment: when i add this code MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            text.setText(message);
                        }
                    });  the app crash if i change the pos of the code under while it will not crash but i can get the messages

Comment: try to send the activity as argument to Thread, and use it instead of MainActivity.this.... otherwise, if it does not work send log pls

Comment: Is it crashing because `text` is null?

Comment: The logcat will tell you all. Spend time to get used with the logcat. I told you that before. No need to start a new thread tf you dont know the logcat.

Comment: Call runOnUiThread() AFTER the while loop. First collect the whole message.

Comment: Why are you posting onClick() code. It's not used is it? It has nothing to do with your problem? By the way your onClick code will produce an Exception.

Comment: `text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);` Put that in onCreate() before you start the thread. Why are you naming that as `text`? Very confusing. It's no text but a TextView.

Comment: So in your logcat you will see that you had a NullPointerException because text was null. Learn to use the logcat!